# Create 'groups' that users can join, what would be a good approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, join

I want to build "groups" that users can join,
The flow of steps and things needed is in my head but the code to build this lacks some bit since I'm still learning rails. I would like to ask some advice on your ideas best practice of what would be needed to accomplish below:

- You can create a group with a name 'test'
- You automatically join the group test, other users can join to
- If want to see a list of the users joined my group 'test'

Im thinking of creating a model sessions like
groups|name|
But then how could I store the multiple users that are in this session?
Should I make an array of the user_id's for example and make an extra column like
groups|name|user_ids ?

What would be best practice and what rails (3) methods could I use to get a very rough version of the above functionality up and running ?

Comment: Do you want to achieve the above with devise or custom authentication (your own session handling...)?  The purpose of sessions though is to be a unique means of identifying users, aren't you better off managing/tracking such via a user role.

Comment: Maybe the terms "sessions" is a bit causing for confusing, this is not about authenticating users or logging them in, I use devise for that already, these are "sessions" separated from devise, a better name for sessions instead would be "Group" I edited above post to change that since it causes for confusion

Comment: So the question would change to: How to know which users of a group are currently active? To know which users `belong_to` a group is easy ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand this is a many to many relationship. So you would have 3 models :

```
class User < AR
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < AR
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < AR
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

and to know what users belong to a group :

```
@group = Group.find_by_name("test")
@users_group = @group.users
```

### Update

to ensure the user creating the group also belongs to it :

```
# in group_controller.rb
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:group])
  @group.users << current_user

  if @group.save
    # ... etc
  end
end
```

of course the `current_user` should exist/be logged in with the usual `before_filter` (if I remember correctly its `authenticate!` with devise)

Comment: Thanks this indeed seems like a reasonable solution and I have thought to complex. I try this out as im still learning rails. What If I wanted to know also who "initiated" the group. I forgot to mention that in the openingspost, 1 user can create this group and other can join but then I would need to know this 1 user that started the group.

Comment: Hi I updated the answer. That is one way to do it. you can also pass the current user id in the params[:group] as a hidden field and create a virtual attribute that sets the association correctly. Watch ryan bates railscasts they'll teach a huge lot...

Comment: Working on this though Im confused over the columns each table should hold to make this work  participants table has |id|created_at|updated_at currently wich can't be right

Comment: participants table needs a user_id and a group_id to join users and groups.

Comment: Figured it out myself already thanks, Im going to search for some more to more relationship info/screencast to better understand the way it works coming from a php world rails is still new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'm creating a new thread, but I am unable to comment as of my new status right now.

@charlysisto your answer for this question involves a User, Membership, and Group class. I understand the need of User and Group, but I am confused to why we would need a Membership class. If anything doesn't it make more sense to have a Groups class with Group?

```
    class User < AR
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :groups, :through => :group
    end

    class Groups < AR
    has_many :groups
    has_many :users, :through => :group
    end

    class Group < AR
    has_many :users
    belongs_to :groups
    end
```

What do you think?

Comment: oups sorry late answer. Groups is plural and doesn't fit with the ActiveRecord Pattern which represents a singular row of a table